"SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 16.2 SDK. All iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later"
For some time using Gitlab CI there is a permanent issue:

[17:39:27]: [33m[altool] 2024-05-14 17:39:27.338 *** Error: Asset validation failed SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 16.2 SDK. All iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution. (ID: 713999ac-ec13-4b2b-a933-52ec2d927b38) (90725)
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]  {
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]     NSLocalizedDescription = "Asset validation failed";
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]     NSLocalizedFailureReason = "SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 16.2 SDK. All iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution. (ID: 713999ac-ec13-4b2b-a933-52ec2d927b38)";
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]     "original_server_error" =     {
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]         code = "STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90725";
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]         detail = "SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 16.2 SDK. All iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution.";
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]         id = "713999ac-ec13-4b2b-a933-52ec2d927b38";
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]         status = 409;
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]         title = "Asset validation failed";
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool]     };
[0m
[17:39:27]: [33m[altool] }
[0m
[17:39:27]: Application Loader output above ^
[17:39:27]: [31mERROR: WILL RETRY PART 1. Failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002c58600 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _NSURLErrorNWResolutionReportKey=Resolved 0 endpoints in 27ms using udp from cache, _NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask ., _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
[0m

Everything is updated to the latest version on my Machine:

os 14 (Sonoma)
Xcode 15.3

Xcode 15 and iOS 17SDK is the only sdk installed on my Mac
App is designed for ios. I upload everything using Fastlane. Why it says it is build with 16.2? How can I workaround it? I have read a lot about that, tried everything, and it still creates the same error.

I had the same problem on Mos 14 (Sonoma) with Xcode version 15.3.
To solve the problem you just need to update os and Xcode. This will solve the problem. Evidently with such errors Apple forces it's users to update os. As everything was working before new os release.
